# Capturing InputEvents from a JPanel containing an Applet

Tags: java, swing, events, jpanel

I have a `JPanel` to which I add an `java.awt.Applet`. If I add an input listener, like a `MouseListener` directly to the panel, I will be able to receive events when I click on the blank panel, as expected. However, when I add the applet, which completely fills the panel, the listener no longer picks up mouse clicks, presses, etc. So I figured that I would try adding the `MouseListener` to the actual applet, but the listener did not receive any events when I clicked on the applet. I know for a fact that the applet uses listeners of its own, but I don't think that would be the cause of this, though possible.

I tried using a glass pane with the `JFrame` containing the panel, and then adding a `MouseListener` to the glass frame and delegating input events to the component lying directly under the point at which the event occurred. I figured that way I would be able to receive events but not lose functionality. However, I found that method to be a little messy and I could not get it to work. I've also tried using the `setComponentZOrder` function but that was confusing to use and I could not get it to work either.

What am I doing wrong? How can I capture input events from an `Applet` or a `JPanel` containing (only) an applet?

Thanks.

Comment: The applet (probably) contains other components which are trapping the events before they reach either the applet it self or your container (think of mouse events like rain drops and mouse listeners like umbrellas, if you're covered by an umbrella, you don't get wet...or mouse on...).  You "might" be able to use a `AWTEventListener`, but that is rather low level and lots of awesome trouble...Why do you want to get notification of mouse events from under the applet any way?

Comment: @MadProgrammer The applet does contain a `Canvas`. I need to get mouse event notifications because I'm writing automation software and I need to be able to intercept mouse (and keyboard) events before they reach the game client (i.e., the applet) so that any custom overlays that are part of the automation software (the script) can be notified that they were clicked on (the overlays are drawn on top of the game client).